# Excel sunburst chart: Some labels missing

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I've made a sunburst chart in Excel (2016) and want to add labels to all data points. The problem is, that Excel discards some of the labels automatically:

[image: Example]

It seems that labels are removed either because the datapoint is too small or the label string too long. How can I get Excel to show all labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. Sunburst graph doesn't seem to be able to align the data labels in a custom way (labels outside area).

---

You could achieve a very close graph with a Doughnut chart. Needs some more modification but is doable.

**Result:**

[image]

**Step-by-Step guide:**

We start with rearrange the data. We crate two tables. 1st table is for the region part and the 2nd table is for the sub region part.

For Region 3, I sum all the sub region values (50+60+1 = 111).

I mark the inner circle first, which will be my Region parts, and then I create a Doughnut Chart.

[image]

Add second serie.

I add my second serie which will be the Sub regions.

[image]

Modify size of circular sectors.

I click on one serie and go to "Series Options" (small green bars), then I rotate my chart by "Angle of first slice" (285 = 90 degrees for "sub region 2) in your example) to 300 degrees and I also make each series thicker by set "Doughnut Hole Size" to 40%.

[image]

Add data labels.

Right click on the series and choose "Add Data Labels" -> "Add Data Labels". Do it for both series.

[image]

Modify the data labels

Click on the labels for one series (I took sub region), then go to: "Label Options" (small green bars).
Untick the "Value". Then click on the "Value From Cells". In the little window mark your range. For Sub Region I choose range B2:B7 (The whole sub region range, since we want it proportionally correct).

[image]

Do the same for Region Part, Here I choose range A13:A16 to represent my data label range.

[image]

Edit each circular sector so they match.

I click on a single circular sector (blue outer area), see picture below:

[image]

Then go to "Fill & Line" and choose "No Fill" for the areas that shouldn't be visible.
For the other areas that should match (Sub Region 1, Sub Region 2 and Sub Region 3) I choose "Solid Fill" (below "No Fill") and match it with with Region 3 colour.

Last thing I did was to delete the legend in the bottom of my chart.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly

Comment: Was very fun to create :), thanks for the question and the challange. Take care =)!!

Answer (score 1):

If found that when I made by chart area really, really large then opened the Chart Design Tab and selected a few different styles, my labels magically appeared, and I could then go back to my original style choice and they were there. The labels are pretty tiny, but they're there.  I could then select the forat Plot Area, Plot Area Options, Data Labels, I could resize the fonts. No idea if this will print or not, but so far so good....